# Windows Server 2008 R2 install: what is ENTERPRISEV?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, installation

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 installation disk. There are quite a few choices for the version of Windows Server to install (Datacenter, Web, Standard, etc.)

But there are several versions that have a "V" version. For example, there is a choice for ENTERPRISE and one for ENTERPRISEV. Here is a screen shot: 
[image]

What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 4):

I've never seen this before. Can you post a photograph or screenshot?

You should see 8 choices, one for each version of Windows, and for each version you can choose server core (no GUI) or full.

If this is something new I suspect it's just that version with HyperV pre-installed.

This is what you should be seeing:

[image]

Comment: Added a screenshot as requested.

Comment: Looks like you may be using a debugger or test installer disk: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserversetup/thread/92686173-2e22-4881-af3b-1fa0cfb50b32

Comment: Or maybe that's some kind of OEM disk? I'd go to technet and download an official ISO just to be safe.

Comment: It's from MSDN.

Comment: The file I have is called: SW_DVD5_Windows_Svr_DC_EE_SE_Web_2008_R2_64Bit_English_w_SP1_MLF_X17-22580.ISO